# Does either each entry OR the trace of the resolvent of a real matrix map the upper half plane to itself? If so, how to prove it?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory

Let $M \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be a **real** matrix. Let $\sigma(M)$ denote the set of eigenvalues of $M$. Let $R_M:\mathbb{C} \setminus  \sigma(M) \to \mathbb{C}^{d \times d} $ be the function $R_M(z):= (M-zI)^{-1} \in \mathbb{C}^{d \times d} $ denote the resolvent of the matrix $M$.

**Then is it true that:**

(1) *If the imaginary part of $z$ is positve, i.e. $I(z) > 0$, then must each entry of $I(R_M(z)) > 0$, i.e. be positive as well?*

(2) **If the above is NOT true**, then can we at least have (somewhat weakly):

*If $I(z) > 0$, then $I(trace(R_M(z))) > 0$?*

It's easy to see in dimension $d=1$, but how do we prove it in higher dimensions? Thanks!